# .clang-format function parameter consecutive alignment

Tags: c++, clang, clang-format

Is there anyway for me to achieve this in .clang-format?

Currently I have these three lines of code:

```cpp
displayUtilizationLevel( disp, util, "CPU", k_StartRow, k_StartColumn, flag::displayLength::standard );
displayUtilizationLevel( disp, mem, "MEM", k_StartRow + 1, k_StartColumn, flag::displayLength::standard );
displayUtilizationLevel( disp, swap, "SWAP", k_StartRow + 2, k_StartColumn, flag::displayLength::standard );
```

and I would like them to be formatted as the following:

```cpp
displayUtilizationLevel( disp, util, "CPU" , k_StartRow    , k_StartColumn, flag::displayLength::standard );
displayUtilizationLevel( disp, mem , "MEM" , k_StartRow + 1, k_StartColumn, flag::displayLength::standard );
displayUtilizationLevel( disp, swap, "SWAP", k_StartRow + 2, k_StartColumn, flag::displayLength::standard );
```

Is this possible to achieve?